# How to call function with same name as class member

Tags: c++, scope, scope-resolution

How can I call non-member function `listen()` (included from `sys/socket.h`) from a class which defines a member function with the same name `listen()`?

```
#include <sys/socket.h>

void Socket::listen(int port)
{
    ...

    listen(sock_fd, 10); // this doesn't work
}
```

Comment: [scope resolution operator](https://www.google.com/search?q=scope+resolution+operator&oq=scope+resolution+operator&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.383j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the scope resolution operator `::`.

```
void Socket::listen(int port){
    //...
    ::listen(sock_fd, 10);
    ^^
}
```

The scope resolution operator `::` is used to identify and disambiguate identifiers used in different scopes.